# Setting default language culture for proofing while creating a word document programmatically using Novacode.DocX

Tags: novacode-docx

I have created a word document using Novacode.docX. I want to set its default language culture to English US so that whenever its gets downloaded from the application should be open in default language that has been setup programmatically using NovaCode.DocX Library (for proofreading/spellchecking of the document). Is it possible?